# Android ADB keeps crashing - can't debug on device when using a usb 3.0 port

Tags: android, eclipse, usb, ddms, android-sdk-tools

I just bought a new pc. Installed all the stuff to develop android apps, just like on my old pc. I've installed eclipse Juno on my new pc incase it matters..

Here is the problem, i cant debug on a real device. On any AVD it works just fine, but when i try to run a project on my real device (Galaxy Nexus) i get the following erros:

**first run** i get:

```
   [2012-10-12 09:55:17 - SlideMenuExample] Android Launch!
   [2012-10-12 09:55:17 - SlideMenuExample] adb is running normally.
   [2012-10-12 09:55:17 - SlideMenuExample] Performing com.coboltforge.slidemenuexample.MainActivity activity launch
   [2012-10-12 09:55:21 - SlideMenuExample] Uploading SlideMenuExample.apk onto device '0149C6F11601A009'
   [2012-10-12 09:55:26 - SlideMenuExample] Failed to install SlideMenuExample.apk on device '0149C6F11601A009': timeout
   [2012-10-12 09:55:26 - SlideMenuExample] Launch canceled!
```

**second run**:

```
[2012-10-12 10:01:48 - SlideMenuExample] Android Launch!
[2012-10-12 10:01:48 - SlideMenuExample] adb is running normally.
[2012-10-12 10:01:48 - SlideMenuExample] Performing com.coboltforge.slidemenuexample.MainActivity activity launch
[2012-10-12 10:01:53 - SlideMenuExample] Uploading SlideMenuExample.apk onto device '0149C6F11601A009'
[2012-10-12 10:01:53 - SlideMenuExample] Installing SlideMenuExample.apk...
[2012-10-12 10:01:54 - SlideMenuExample] Success!
[2012-10-12 10:01:54 - SlideMenuExample] Failed to install SlideMenuExample.apk on device '0149C6F11601A009': device not found
[2012-10-12 10:01:54 - SlideMenuExample] com.android.ddmlib.InstallException: device not found
[2012-10-12 10:01:54 - SlideMenuExample] Launch canceled!
```

**third run** gets stuck on launching project on 100%, than nothing happends.

**fourth run**: Yes finnaly the app is succesfully installed (probleb solved? nope)

**fifth run** gets stuck again on 100% and eclipse crashed completely. After i got eclipse restarted i see the following error in the error log:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.AdtPlugin.getDisplay(AdtPlugin.java:334)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.launch.AndroidLaunchController.launch(AndroidLaunchController.java:595)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.launch.LaunchConfigDelegate.doLaunch(LaunchConfigDelegate.java:322)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.launch.LaunchConfigDelegate.launch(LaunchConfigDelegate.java:238)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:855)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:704)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin.buildAndLaunch(DebugUIPlugin.java:1047)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin$8.run(DebugUIPlugin.java:1251)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
```

Please can anyone help me with solving this.

- I already re-installed eclipse and android SDK.
- run eclipse as admin
- adding platform-tools and tools folder of the android sdk to
  enviroment variables
- Increasing ADB connection time out to 20000

**EDIT**
At the back of my pc i got two 2.0 usb-ports (not 3.0 like the the ports in the front). I dont get any trouble when using them..

but i'm still interested why the usb 3.0 port dont work?

Comment: You've said it's specific to USB3, but it might be worth mentioning that running Eclipse as root can be a little tricky due to the ADB daemon which can live before and after, and be restarted during, the lifetime of Eclipse. What do you see if you work from command line? For example, `sudo killall adb; adb devices; adb install foo.apk`?

Comment: I have the same problem on a new MacbookAir 2013 (which comes with USB 3). The previous (USB2 based) MBA didn't have problems. Now this happens all the time with different devices and with/without hubs in between. Even a simple Nexus 4 directly connected to the USB port. It's extremely annoying. Sadly the MBA doesn't have USB2 ports…

Answer (score 0):

I don't know - adb.exe is always crashing. All of my ports are USB 3.0. Windows 7, latest updated, Google USB Driver, latest update (9).

Uninstalled the Google USB Driver and the problem went away...

Comment: I dont have the Google USB Driver, but my ADB still keep crashing... pfff